# WPF Creating different ListBox row templates based on a bound value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I do not have any code at the moment to share. Just a design question.

I have a class that defines a label, and an associated entry type, which I would like to bind to a ListBox. If the type is for example, "Postal Code", I need the ListBox to create the row as a TextBlock and a TextBox. For "Yes/no", I need it to know instead to create a TextBlock with a CheckBox beside it. There will likely be 7 or 8 of these different row types.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`ItemTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) Property.  This property allows you to provide custom logic for choosing which template to use for each item in a collection.

First define your various templates in a resource dictionary...

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
      <!-- template here -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
      <!-- template here -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then, create a custom DataTemplateSelector...

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    var myObj= item as MyObject;
    if (myObj != null) 
    {
      if (myObj.MyType is PostalCode)
      {
         return Application.Resources["TextBoxTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
      }
      if (myObj.MyType  is YesNo)
      {
        return Application.Resources["CheckBoxTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
      }
    }

    return null; 
  }
}
```

Then, its just a matter of using the `ItemTemplateSelector` property...

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="tempSelector" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding items}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tempSelector}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Just a note that if you set the `DataType` property of the `DataTemplate` then you shouldn't need to use a `DataTemplateSelector` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)  class.

> A DataTrigger allows you to set property values when the property value of the data object matches a specified Value.

Alternatively, you can use the [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)  class.

> Typically, you create a DataTemplateSelector when you have more than one DataTemplate for the same type of objects and you want to supply your own logic to choose a DataTemplate to apply based on the properties of each data object.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this would be to have a collection property containing all of the items that you want to see in your `ListBox`, bind that collection to a control that displays lists of items, and use different data templates to change the visuals used for each type of item.

For example, you might have a postal code type:

```
public class PostalCodeEntry
{
    public string Value { get; set; }  // Implement using standard INotifyPropertyChanged pattern
}
```

And a "Boolean" type:

```
public class BooleanEntry
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }  // Implement using standard INotifyPropertyChanged pattern
}
```

You said you wanted a label for each entry type, so a base class would be a good idea:

```
public abstract class EntryBase
{
    public string Label { get; set; }  // Implement using standard INotifyPropertyChanged pattern
}
```

Then `BooleanEntry` and `PostalCodeEntry` would derive from `EntryBase`.

That's the *Models* sorted. You just need a collection of these so that you can bind to them from the UI. Add an appropriate collection property to your `Window` or *ViewModel*:

```
public ObservableCollection<EntryBase> Entries { get; private set; }
```

In your UI (the *View*, implemented in XAML), use an instance of a control that knows how to bind to a list of items and visualize them. In WPF this would be an `ItemsControl` or a control that derives from it such as `ListBox` or `ListView`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" />
```

You can see how we bind the `ItemsSource` property to our code-behind property named `Entries`. The `ItemsControl` (and its descendants) knows how to convert those items into a visual representation. By default, your custom object (`EntryBase` in our example) will be converted into a string and displayed as a text block. However, by using [data templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can control how the conversion from object to visual happens.

If you add a couple of data templates to the resources section like so:

```
<Window ... xmlns:my="clr-namespace:---your namespace here---">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:PostalCodeEntry}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:BooleanEntry}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}" IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then add the `<ItemsControl ...` element after that, then you should see a `TextBlock`/`TextBox` combo for `PostalCodeEntry` types and a `CheckBox` for `BooleanEntry` types.

Hopefully if you can get this working it will give you an idea how you could extend it to cope with other model types and their matching data templates.

Comment: This is a great solution